# Replay / Reset messages in Apache Pulsar

Tags: java, apache-pulsar, pulsar, python-pulsar

Is it possible to replay old messages (within retention period)? There is no documentation about it. I would like to do this based on a timestamp or period.

A hint in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by manually going through the Admin client:

```
 adminClient.topics().resetCursor("topictest", "sub-1", milis);
```

You can reset/replay for all consumers/subscribers by first retrieving a list of the subscribers:

```
adminClient.topics().getSubscriptions("topictest")
```